# Questions about "partial negation"

Tags: sentence

Does a sentence like "According to a report, all the dogs don't like to be hugged" mean " None of the dogs likes to be hugged", or does it mean "some dogs like to be hugged"? Is "all... not" a fixed form of partial negation？

Answer (score 6):

This construction is one of my personal pet peeves, but it's commonly used this way and I should keep my peeve to myself and consider it valid.

That is, if we mean "some of X is not Y," I would *prefer* "not all of X is Y," but it's quite common to find "all of X is not Y." For instance, the famous quote/proverb is usually given as ["All that glitters is not gold."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_that_glitters_is_not_gold) To my overly critical mind, this *ought* to mean "Every single glittery thing, including gold, is not gold." But of course the intent is "*not all* that glitters is gold." (Of course, Shakespeare's version of that quote couldn't have used my preferred order and still have fit into iambic pentameter. But that Wikipedia article shows an earlier version in Chaucer that uses "all ... is not" as well as one that uses "not all.")

Now, this can also lead to confusion. What about the sentence "Everyone doesn't want tomato on their sandwich"? Do *some* want tomato? But context will usually clarify. This "tomato" example so strongly suggests "no one wants it" that it would be a strange choice for partial negation, unless immediately clarified:

> "Does everyone want tomato?"
> "No, *everyone* doesn't want it; only Jim does."

Even then I think I've invented an unlikely example here. Or for the opposite, how about the sentence "Everyone is not here." This would make no sense for complete negation, for existential reasons (there have been questions here about that phrase before). So it would be more likely as an answer to "Is everyone here."

So it would be *rare*—but probably possible—to use this construction in a way that caused ambiguity that the context couldn't resolve.

Comment: I'm quite curious why you say that the proverb "all that glitters is not gold" ought to mean "nothing that glitters is gold" (my phrasing, obviously). The word "all" indicates that there's a universal quantification ("for all *X*, ...") and the word "not" indicates that there's a negation ("it is false that ..."), but what leads you to conclude that the negation should go inside the universal quantification, not outside?

Comment: In other words, what makes "for all *X* that glitters, it is false that *X* is gold" seem like a good interpretation, and "it is false that for all *X* that glitters, *X* is gold" seem like a bad interpretation? I've seen many people express this opinion, so there must be some reason for it, and I'm interested in learning what that reason is.

Comment: @TannerSwett Well, with the disclaimer again that common practice has clearly run counter to this assertion for centuries, so I feel it's unreasonable to insist on: If we call "all" an "inclusion word" and "not" a "negation word," then it's all about what each one is applied to. "*All* that glitters": we're making an inclusive statement about the entire set. "... is not gold": A quality, true of the entire set, is that it is not gold. ...

Comment: @TannerSwett ...  In contrast, "Not all that glitters": We have negated the inclusion. What follows is *not* true of the entire set. "... is gold." The quality of gold is *not* applicable to the entire set. (The real intended meaning.) If you're familiar with javascript, it's the difference between `glittersArray.every(e => e !== gold)` and `!glittersArray.every(e => e === gold)`. The first asserts that no gold is present, the second that some non-gold is present. (For which we ought to use Array.some, but never mind.)

Comment: I think your reasoning makes sense! In the traditional reading of the sentence "all that glitters is not gold," it seems like the word "not" is meant to apply to the entire rest of the sentence... which is a pretty unusual way to apply it, since in most usages of the word "not," we can interpret it as applying to just one of the adjacent words. I have no real opinions or particular points to make here; it's just an interesting thing to mull over.

Answer (score 4):

Idiomaticity:

Question:
"According to a report, all the dogs don't like to be hugged" means [with an s] " None of the dogs likes to be hugged", or does it mean "some dogs like to be hugged"? Is "all... not" a fixed form of partial negation？

That first sample sentence is not really idiomatic as a loose sentence and out of context. Idiomatic would be:

- All dogs like to be hugged.
- No dogs like to be hugged.
- All of the dogs like to be hugged.
- None of the dogs like to be hugged.
  And that's with or without the determiner *the*.

all + don't like to be [past participle] is sub-standard and just sounds unschooled UNLESS it is used in the following way.

*All the dogs don't like to be hugged.* can be a verbal response to this kind of situation:

In a kennel:

"But John, **all the dogs like to be hugged**."

"No, Warren, **all the dogs don't like to be hugged**.

In: According to a report from that kennel, all the dogs don't like to be hugged"

Answer (score 3):

> All dogs don't like to be hugged

is a full negation, the same as

> No dogs like to be hugged.

If you want a partial negation, you should say

> Not all dogs like to be hugged

Comment: I love this answer but don't feel that I can make this assertion as strongly, given the weight of the opposite usage. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it could mean both and the context and the emphasis placed on different parts of the sentence before and after this line could make the interpretation clearer.

So, in this example, the phrase "all... not" is not "strictly" a fixed form of partial negation; its interpretation decides that, which directly depends on the context and structure of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The ***only*** reason anybody would say that is to be deliberately confusing.  I conclude that it means *nothing at all*.

That's because it is not a genuine attempt to communicate. It is at most a joke and at least incompetence. There is no way to know if the person meant "all" or "some", because with such bad English, you can't assume that the person was competent at speaking.

Answer (score 0):

@TannerSwett Regarding the phrase 'All that glitters is not gold' actually does come from a literal blanket meaning of that quality.  The modern treatment of that phrase has come to be an aphorism stating that appearances can be deceptive, synonymous with 'you can't judge a book by it's cover.'  The older meaning of this phrase however is actually referring to real gold not being gold, that is, that the real "gold" is youth, health and living a good life, while for many the aquisition of gold, going after this glittering thing that we may think will bring us the health and more enjoyable life, etc., instead robs people of their lives in pursuit of it.  In Shakespeare's usage of the phrase it is in the same manner, being a warning that the glitter, or "spark of life" you could say, cannot be found in accumulating gold, and that in fact the gold that is accumulated will itself even one day be buried with it's owner never to glitter again.

Regarding Dog Hugs:

We would need to see the entire context of the article to give a definitive answer, but based on the information here the assumption would have to be made that in fact none of the dogs like to be hugged.  The common assumption at least from those who like dogs is that the dog likes to be hugged, but the report could be about that very thing, why they in fact do not like hugs.  Or, the situation in which they are being hugged in the context of the article may be such that dogs are abject to it.  We would need to see the article to know for sure, but if this was our complete data set available and this were a life-or-death type situation we could only take it at face value as a warning not to hug the dogs.